# Помогите разобраться с выводом результатов php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-query

На сайте есть цикл вывода статей из-записей. Не могу разобраться почему цикл выводит только 9 статей (всего статей 15) Как это можно настроить. Так же есть кнопка показать больше, она выводит остальные статьи но дублирует 2 предыдущие.
[ссылка на сайт здесь](https://ortotis-premium.ru/deti-do-12-mesyacev/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php 
    $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type'); 
    $queried_post_term = get_query_var('term');
    $queried_post_taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
    $obj_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $post_standart = true; 
?>

    
    <?php if ($post_standart == true) { ?>
        
        <div class="block results-block">
            <div class="center-1500">
                <h1>Результаты</h1>
                <p class="description">Наши пациенты</p>
                <div class="results-nav">
                    <?php if (has_nav_menu('results')) { wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'results', 'menu_class' => 'menu-result', 'container' => false)); } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="results-list">
                    <?php
                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                            setup_postdata($post);
                            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
                            $countfoto = get_field('галерея');
                            $i = 0; 
                            foreach( $countfoto as $image ) { 
                                $i++; 
                                if ($i == 1) {
                                    $firstimage = $image['url'];
                                }
                            }
                    ?>  
                        <a href="<?php echo $firstimage; ?>" class="item" data-fancybox="result-image-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                            <div class="one">
                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img class="s-full" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/php/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>&w=642&h=690&zc=1&q=90" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                </div>
                                <span><b>Диагноз: </b><?php echo get_field('диагноз'); ?></span>
                                <span><b>Срок лечения: </b><?php echo get_field('срок_лечения'); ?></span>
                                <div class="down">
                                    <div class="left">Все фото</div>
                                    <div class="right"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="two">
                                <span><b>Диагноз: </b><?php echo get_field('диагноз'); ?></span>
                                <span><b>Срок лечения: </b><?php echo get_field('срок_лечения'); ?></span>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <?php echo get_field('описание'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="type"><strong>Все фото</strong></div>
                                <i>(<?php echo count($countfoto); ?>) фото</i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                    <script>
                        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
                        var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
                        var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
                        var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
                    </script>
                    <div class="results-loadmore">
                        <a href="#">Больше результатов</a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $gotopage = false; include 'php/ask-question.php'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    
function resultsloadmores(){
    $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;

    wp_reset_query();
    $query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&paged='.$args['paged']);
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        setup_postdata($post);
        $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');
        $countfoto = get_field('галерея', get_the_ID());
        $i = 0; 
        foreach( $countfoto as $image ) { 
            $i++; 
            if ($i == 1) {
                $firstimage = $image['url'];
            }
        }
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $firstimage; ?>" class="item" data-fancybox="result-image-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="one">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img class="s-full" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/php/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>&w=642&h=690&zc=1&q=90" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                </div>
                <span><b>Диагноз: </b><?php echo get_field('диагноз'); ?></span>
                <span><b>Срок лечения: </b><?php echo get_field('срок_лечения'); ?></span>
                <div class="down">
                    <div class="left">Все фото</div>
                    <div class="right"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <span><b>Диагноз: </b><?php echo get_field('диагноз'); ?></span>
                <span><b>Срок лечения: </b><?php echo get_field('срок_лечения'); ?></span>
                <div class="description">
                    <?php echo get_field('описание'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="type"><strong>Все фото</strong></div>
                <i>(<?php echo count($countfoto); ?>) фото</i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="hide">
            <?php 
                $i = 0; 
                foreach( $countfoto as $image ) { 
                    $i++; 
                    if ($i > 1) {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" data-fancybox="result-image-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"></a>
            <?php 
                    } 
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    die();
} 
 
add_action('wp_ajax_resultsloadmore', 'resultsloadmores');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_resultsloadmore', 'resultsloadmores');
```

Comment: этого не достаточно, исправлять надо в запросах к БД и в формировании вывода

Comment: @JonBrasers а где именно могут быть эти запросы?

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, в этом говне действительно невозможно разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если нужно показывать все посты без постраничной навигации - то вставьте следующий код после строки div class="results-list"

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>

<?php
        query_posts( 
                wp_parse_args(
                        $wp_query->query, ['posts_per_page' => -1]
                )
            );
?>
```

2. Если нужно добавить разбивку по страница - например по 10, то вставьте следующий код после строки div class="results-list"

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>

<?php
        query_posts( 
                wp_parse_args(
                        $wp_query->query, ['posts_per_page' => 10]
                )
            );
?>
```

фрагмент кода

```
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;

wp_reset_query();
$query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&paged='.$args['paged']);
```

замените на

```
$current_page = $_POST['page'] + 1;

$per_page = $args['per_page'];

$offset_start = 1;

$args['offset'] = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;

$args['paged'] = $current_page;

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

3. Также количество записей на странице управляется в админке /wp-admin/options-reading.php - "На страницах блога отображать не более"

Comment: большое вам спасибо
проблема только осталась в том что когда я подгружаю остальные записи, они дублируются

Comment: @GreedyWizards если ответ - верный, то можно его пометить верным и проголосовать

Comment: да частично, с выводом понятно а вот как сделать так называемый офсет для того чтобы записи не дублировались при подгрузке

Comment: @GreedyWizards добавьте параметр offset https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#offset

Comment: добавил но это не помогло

Comment: @GreedyWizards вставьте после $query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&paged='.$args['paged']); строку echo (string)$query->request; и покажите запрос

Comment: ELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp4_posts.ID FROM wp4_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp4_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp4_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp4_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp4_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp4_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp4_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp4_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp4_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1, 10

Comment: @GreedyWizards скорректировал ответ. пункт 2

Comment: Всё скопировал как вы написали спасибо большое Вам, но проблема осталась
выводится с другой категории посты и посты дублируются 
там две категории "дети до 12м" и  "после 12м"
при подзагрузке посты смешиваются 
нужно 12 постов на страницу - выводится всё ок
а когда подгружаешь получается всё в кучу и дублируются посты 
может есть возможность как то по другому это всё реализовать 
подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @GreedyWizards скорректировал ответ. пункт 2 . если в начале Вы работаете в query_posts() с глобальным запросом (в нем уже от страницы куча параметров есть), то в ajax вы в WP_Query должны все параметры сформировать